# change textbox's value from pageload event, submit new values issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a form to update an access DB table.  My issue is that when the text in the text boxes is changed and the form is submitted, the `.text` values stay the same as they were when the `datareader` loaded them on the page load event.  How can I submit the values that the user updates, not what is already there from page load.

Code:

```
     Public Property vehicleid As Integer
            Public Property connstring As String = "myconnectionstring..."
        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     vehicleid = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("vehicID"))
        Dim svEnterdate, stocknum, make, model, color As String

                Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connstring)
                Dim sql As String = "select * from vehicle where vehicleid=@vid"
                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vid", vehicleid)
                conn.Open()
                Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

                While dr.Read
                    svEnterdate = dr("enterdate").ToString()
                    stocknum = dr("stock_num").ToString()
                    make = dr("make").ToString()
                    model = dr("model").ToString()
                    color = dr("color").ToString()
                End While
                conn.Close()
                EnterDateTXT.Text = svEnterdate
                StockNumTXT.Text = stocknum
                MakeTxt.Text = make
                ModelTXT.Text = model
                ColorTxt.Text = color
         End Sub

'inbetween these 2 events the user can manipulate all the controls .text values, yet the 
' .text values of the submitted controls below are the same as the ones filled by the 
'datareader

        Protected Sub SubmitBTN_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitBTN.Click
          Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connstring)
                Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Vehicle" & _
                    " SET stock_num=@stock, make=@make, model=@model, color=@color, enterdate=@enter " & _
                    "WHERE  vehicleid=@vid"
                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vid", vehicleid)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", StockNumTXT.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@make", MakeTxt.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", ModelTXT.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", ColorTxt.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enter", EnterDateTXT.Text)

                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In your page load code, Check For Post back

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

 If Not IsPostBack Then
    ' Write your code to read data from database here
 End

End Sub
```

If you dont check for postback in your page load event, Everytime when you click the submit button, It is going to excute the code in your page load ( load the content again to the text box) first. So whatever you entered in the textbox will be overwritten by the content form the database and that will be saved back again to the database.

To undestand this. Put a breakpoint in your Page_load event code and another in your button click event code. Now enter some value in textbox and click the button and see whether your code block in pageload is executing or not.

Checking the Postback check in your page_load will fix the problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Comment: that solved the problem as far as submitting the correct value, but now I am not seeing any changes in my database.  any chance you see something wrong with maybe my update statements because I am not receiving any errors in debugging

Comment: put a breakpoint before calling executeNonQuery and check What is the value of the variable "sql" copy that and execute it in the SQL server query analyser directly. What are you getting then ?

Comment: When i entered it into access query analyzer it took it perfectly and I was able to update the value. I don't know why it wont update through my prgram

Comment: What is the executeNonQuery returning ? It should return the number of rows affected. Are you sure you are connected to the correct database ? using breakpoint check what is your connection details

Comment: my connection is the same one I am using for my entire project and I have been copying and pasting it so I know that is not the issue.  executenonquery is returning a total of 0 rows affected

Comment: The reason your request won't update is that the button code is fired before the page_load event and the page_load event is where you set the vehicleid, so you are trying to update the database `where vehicleid=0`. You would be much better off moving vehicleid into a readonly property that returns the value of the request variable and remove the local member.